# Estruturas e seleção de condicionais

Tags: c, sintaxe

Boa tarde!

Estou fazendo um programa que lê diversos dados de vacas: entre eles idade, produção, etc. Porém estou em dúvida de como posso interromper o for quando digitar código =0. Pois como está no programa, só será solicitado outros dados se código for diferente de 0. Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
 int i, qtde_leite_mensal, qtde_alim_mes, cont_vaca, cont;
 struct balanco
 {
     int cod;
     int prod_leite_semanal;
     int alim_consumido;
     int idade;
 };

 struct balanco num_vacas[3];
printf("\t\tRelacao de animais (vacas) da fazenda\n\n");

 for(i=0; i<3; i++)
 {

     printf("\n\nInforme o codigo do animal: ");
     scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].cod);

        if(num_vacas[i].cod!=0)
            {

                 printf("Sua producao de leite (litros) semanal: ");
                 scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal);

                 printf("Quantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido por semana: ");
                 scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].alim_consumido);

                 printf("Informe a idade (meses) do animal:");
                 scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].idade);

                         qtde_leite_mensal= num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal*4;
                         printf("Sua producao mensal (litros) de leite e: %d", qtde_leite_mensal);

                         qtde_alim_mes=num_vacas[i].alim_consumido*4;
                         printf("Quantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido (mensal): %d ", qtde_alim_mes);

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para interromper o `for` quando o usuário informar o **codigo == 0**, basta criar um `else` depois do seu `if` e utilizar uma `break`. Segue abaixo o  código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    int i, qtde_leite_mensal, qtde_alim_mes, cont_vaca, cont;
     struct balanco
     {
         int cod;
         int prod_leite_semanal;
         int alim_consumido;
         int idade;
     };

    struct balanco num_vacas[3];
    printf("\t\tRelacao de animais (vacas) da fazenda\n\n");

     for(i=0; i<3; i++)
     {

         printf("\n\nInforme o codigo do animal: ");
         scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].cod);

            if(num_vacas[i].cod!=0)
                {

                     printf("Sua producao de leite (litros) semanal: ");
                     scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal);

                     printf("Quantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido por semana: ");
                     scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].alim_consumido);

                     printf("Informe a idade (meses) do animal:");
                     scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].idade);

                             qtde_leite_mensal= num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal*4;
                             printf("Sua producao mensal (litros) de leite e: %d", qtde_leite_mensal);

                             qtde_alim_mes=num_vacas[i].alim_consumido*4;
                             printf("Quantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido (mensal): %d ", qtde_alim_mes);

                }
                else
                    break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

adiciona este if depois do scanf:

```
if(num_vacas[i].cod == 0) break;
```

o 'break' que vai fazer o teu loop encerrar.

Comment: Já que existe `if(num_vacas[i].cod!=0)`, seria mais fácil fazer `else break;`