# Estrutura de seleção, uso do for

Tags: c, sintaxe

Preciso selecionar os animais com mais de (60 meses), e retornar seu consumo e produção mensal, como tentei idealizar nas equações. Porém, não retorna nenhum número corretamente.

```
 for(i=0; i<3; i++)
 {

     printf("\n\nInforme o codigo do animal: ");
     scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].cod);

        if(num_vacas[i].cod!=0)
            {

                 printf("Sua producao de leite (litros) semanal: ");
                 scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal);

                 printf("Quantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido por semana: ");
                 scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].alim_consumido);

                 printf("Informe a idade (meses) do animal:");
                 scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].idade);

                         qtde_leite_mensal= num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal*4;
                         printf("\n\tSua producao mensal (litros) de leite e: %d", qtde_leite_mensal);

                         qtde_alim_mes=num_vacas[i].alim_consumido*4;
                         printf("\n\tQuantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido (mensal): %d ", qtde_alim_mes);

            }
        else
            break;

 }

 if(num_vacas[i].cod!=0)
 {

             for(i=0; i<3; i++)
             {
                  cont_vaca= num_vacas[i].idade/12;
                  if(cont_vaca>=5)
                  {
                    cont++;

                  }
            }
         printf("Numero de vacas que podem ser vendidas (5 anos ou mais): %d", cont);
         }
         soma_prod=0;
         soma_consumo=0;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if(num_vacas[i].idade>=60)
            {
              soma_prod= soma_prod + (num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal*4);
              soma_consumo= soma_consumo + (num_vacas[i].alim_consumido*4);
            }
        }

        printf(" A producao de leite das vacas com possibilidade de venda: %d ", soma_prod);
        printf(" O gasto com alimento das mesmas: %d ", soma_consumo)
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (não é duplicata): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99604/132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, vamos tentar arrumar o seu código.

Primeira coisa, ao invés disso:

```
if (condicao) {
     // Um monte
     // de linhas
     // aqui
     // a perder
     // de vista.
} else
    break;
```

Fica mais fácil de entender assim:

```
if (!condicao) break;
// Continua o fluxo aqui
// sem precisar se preocupar com um
// else que vem depois.
// O código fica bem mais fácil de
// entender.
```

Dito isso, após reidentar o seu código, temos isso:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    printf("\n\nInforme o codigo do animal: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].cod);

    if (num_vacas[i].cod == 0) break;
    printf("Sua producao de leite (litros) semanal: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal);
    printf("Quantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido por semana: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].alim_consumido);

    printf("Informe a idade (meses) do animal:");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].idade);

    qtde_leite_mensal = num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal * 4;
    printf("\n\tSua producao mensal (litros) de leite e: %d", qtde_leite_mensal);

    qtde_alim_mes = num_vacas[i].alim_consumido * 4;
    printf("\n\tQuantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido (mensal): %d ", qtde_alim_mes);
 }

 if (num_vacas[i].cod != 0) {
     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         cont_vaca = num_vacas[i].idade / 12;
         if (cont_vaca >= 5) cont++;
     }
     printf("Numero de vacas que podem ser vendidas (5 anos ou mais): %d", cont);
 }
 soma_prod = 0;
 soma_consumo = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     if (num_vacas[i].idade >= 60) {
         soma_prod = soma_prod + (num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal * 4);
         soma_consumo = soma_consumo + (num_vacas[i].alim_consumido * 4);
     }
 }

 printf(" A producao de leite das vacas com possibilidade de venda: %d ", soma_prod);
 printf(" O gasto com alimento das mesmas: %d ", soma_consumo)
```

Bem, vamos focar neste trecho:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     // Um pouco de código...
     if (num_vacas[i].cod == 0) break;
     // Um monte de código...
 }
 if (num_vacas[i].cod != 0) {
     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         cont_vaca = num_vacas[i].idade / 12;
         if (cont_vaca >= 5) cont++;
     }
     printf("Numero de vacas que podem ser vendidas (5 anos ou mais): %d", cont);
 }
```

Primeiramente, olhe para aquele `if` logo após o `for`. Ele usa o valor `i`. Quem é `i`? A resposta é que se o `for` anterior chegou ao final, então `i` vale 3, e neste caso acessar `num_vacas[i].cod` provavelmente não vai fazer o que você quer. Por outro lado, se o `break` tiver sido executado, então o que está dentro deste `if` não vai rodar. Ou seja, em todos os casos, provavelmente o programa não vai fazer o que você quer.

Considerando que dentro do `if` há um `for`, eu acho que o `if` não deveria estar ali. Então a minha sugestão é simplesmente eliminar o `if` e deixar o código assim:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     // Um pouco de código...
     if (num_vacas[i].cod == 0) break;
     // Um monte de código...
 }
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     cont_vaca = num_vacas[i].idade / 12;
     if (cont_vaca >= 5) cont++;
 }
 printf("Numero de vacas que podem ser vendidas (5 anos ou mais): %d", cont);
 soma_prod = 0;
 soma_consumo = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     if (num_vacas[i].idade >= 60) {
         soma_prod = soma_prod + (num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal * 4);
         soma_consumo = soma_consumo + (num_vacas[i].alim_consumido * 4);
     }
 }
```

Por fim, os três laços estão iterando de 0 a 2, e se o código for 0, tudo deve ser interrompido. Desta forma, pode-se combinar os três laços em um só e eles podem ser simplificados assim:

```
int soma_prod = 0;
int soma_consumo = 0;
int i = 0;
int cont = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("\n\nInforme o codigo do animal: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].cod);

    if (num_vacas[i].cod == 0) break;
    printf("Sua producao de leite (litros) semanal: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal);
    printf("Quantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido por semana: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].alim_consumido);

    printf("Informe a idade (meses) do animal:");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].idade);

    int qtde_leite_mensal = num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal * 4;
    printf("\n\tSua producao mensal (litros) de leite e: %d", qtde_leite_mensal);

    int qtde_alim_mes = num_vacas[i].alim_consumido * 4;
    printf("\n\tQuantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido (mensal): %d ", qtde_alim_mes);

    if (num_vacas[i].idade >= 60) {
        cont++;
        soma_prod += num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal * 4;
        soma_consumo += num_vacas[i].alim_consumido * 4;
    }
}
```

E observe também que o melhor é declarar as variáveis no menor escopo possível quando você for precisar dela, tal como eu fiz acima. Recomendo que faça o mesmo com todas as demais variáveis.

Ainda há mais uns detalhes que dá para melhorar. Perceba que o `num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal * 4` e o `num_vacas[i].alim_consumido * 4` aparecem repetidos. Podemos eliminar as repetições, e este é o código final resultante:

```
int soma_prod = 0;
int soma_consumo = 0;
int i = 0;
int cont = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("\n\nInforme o codigo do animal: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].cod);

    if (num_vacas[i].cod == 0) break;
    printf("Sua producao de leite (litros) semanal: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal);
    printf("Quantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido por semana: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].alim_consumido);

    printf("Informe a idade (meses) do animal:");
    scanf("%d", &num_vacas[i].idade);

    int qtde_leite_mensal = num_vacas[i].prod_leite_semanal * 4;
    printf("\n\tSua producao mensal (litros) de leite e: %d", qtde_leite_mensal);

    int qtde_alim_mes = num_vacas[i].alim_consumido * 4;
    printf("\n\tQuantidade (quilos) de alimento consumido (mensal): %d ", qtde_alim_mes);

    if (num_vacas[i].idade >= 60) {
        cont++;
        soma_prod += qtde_leite_mensal;
        soma_consumo += qtde_alim_mes;
    }
}
```

Há mais simplificações possíveis, especialmente se você colocar `&num_vacas[i]` em uma variável de tipo ponteiro logo no início deste `for`.

E note também um outro detalhe: Ao juntar os três `for`s em um só, eu eliminei um bug. O que acontecia é que se o usuário digitasse o código 0 após colocar os dados da vaca 0 e da vaca 1, por exemplo, ao acessar o `num_vacas[2].prod_leite_semanal` e o `num_vacas[2].alim_consumido` no terceiro `for`, estes valores que não foram preenchidos (e portanto o conteúdo seria algum lixo largado na memória) seriam somado à `soma_prod` e `soma_consumo`, corrompendo o seu cálculo. Ao juntar tudo em um só `for`, este problema desaparece.

Comment: Caro Victor muito obrigado! Você me ajudou muito! Abraço!